# Why is it so complicated to have an upgrade mechanism that works?

Tags: upgrade

Running Ubuntu 14.04 (for now...) on a MacBookPro.
I'm stuck with a full boot partition.
No, sudo apt-get clean won't change a thing, stop repeating this to me.
Looks to me like the default partition setup, when I first install this  OS, just made boot too small, when it knew it was going to keep for no reason all previous version of its own kernel, every time it asks for update or upgrade (it's so clear...)

How do I fix this once and for all ?
If it involves reformating the whole drive, it will be done with another OS. A one that works.

Comment: make a larger boot partition

Comment: Sounds like your problem is a little something called "operator error"

Comment: Upgrade doesn't _automatically_ remove old kernels, correct. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu

Comment: A quick web search got me to the the `purge-old-kernels` script in the "bikeshed" package, which semi-automates this upgrade task.

Comment: Although poorly worded from a frustrated user, it is a good question. I suggest you file a bug report / feature request outlining the common problem of having a /boot partition full due to the number of kernels. Other distros *fedora* limit the number of kernels on the system by default likely because fedora uses LVM by default (and thus a full /boot is more common).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the older (unused) kernel packages. From [How to Remove unwanted Kernels from your system](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel),

> Open the Synaptic package manager from the System->Administration menu. Click the “Search” button on the tool bar and search for "linux-image-2". The results should show every available and installed kernel. A green box on the left indicates that the package is installed. The only linux-image you want installed is the latest one. Find the package corresponding to the kernel to you running currently (this is the kernel you found in the terminal window). Make sure you keep that one. Now you can uninstall the old kernels from the list by clicking their boxes and selecting “Mark for Removal”.

You can also get your current kernel with `uname -a`